# Nginx Rule for URL redirect

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, redirect, nginx-location

I am stuck in writing a simple nginx rewrite/redirect rule for below.

Eg: Any request for  `https://example.com/news/abcxyz-pqr`

should be redirected to

```
https://example.com/news-and-articles/abcxyz-pqr
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below rule worked for me perfectly.

```
rewrite ^/news/(.*)$ /news-and-articles/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer. Its perfectly ok :)